# calculate hex checksum in python

Tags: python

I need to write a function to calculate the checksum of its argument
and then send the parameter with it's checksum out.

When I was calculating the checksum manually i was doing something like this:

```
data = '\x03\x2F\x00\x00\x02\x12\x01\x47'
```

and then

```
s.sendall(data)
```

is there a way to write data as:

```
data = "03 2F 00 00 02 12 01"
```

and let python know that I want what's in data to be
seen as Hex? 
If python views that as hex will my function look like

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    sum = sum +data[i]
```

or something like that?

Comment: Please put more description to your question. How your input looks like, where/how you store it...etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To represent as hexadecimal, use `binascii.hexlify`:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify('\x03\x2F\x00\x00\x02\x12\x01\x47')
'032f000002120147'
>>> ' '.join(binascii.hexlify(ch) for ch in '\x03\x2F\x00\x00\x02\x12\x01\x47')
'03 2f 00 00 02 12 01 47'
```

To calculate checksum, iterate each bytes:

```
data = '\x03\x2F\x00\x00\x02\x12\x01\x47'

checksum = 0
for ch in data:
    checksum += ord(ch)  # ord('\x03`) -> 3
```

or using [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
checksum = sum(map(ord, data))
```

Comment: Found a more straight forward answer here in case anyone stumbles across this for if you read ord it does not work with a hexalified version of the binary data nor the straight binary data I was receiving: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744391/calculate-hex-checksum-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect to see this:?

```
input ='\x03\x2F\x00\x00\x02\x12\x01\x47'
output = ' '.join([('{:02X}'.format(ord(c))) for c in input])
print(output)
```

prints:

> 03 2F 00 00 02 12 01 47

If not - clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to read these in as values, correct?  Try:

```
val = '5c'
hval = int(val, 16)
print hval
```

> > 92

(which is 0x5C in decimal)

To go the other direction:

```
val = '%x' % 92
print val
```

> > '5c'

Answer (score 1):

```
data = "03 2f 00 00 02 12 01 47"

for letter in data.replace(' ', '').decode('hex'):
    print hex(ord(letter))

0x3
0x2f
0x0
0x0
0x2
0x12
0x1
0x47
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was trying to do

```
def sum_words(data):
    return sum(int(x, 16) for x in data.split())

data = "03 2F 00 00 02 12 01"
print(sum_words(data))
```